# What is this ip for?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, ip, wan

I'm connected to a typical home router by wifi . Checking nm-applet in ubuntu xenial , i see that i have one IPv4 configured & one IPv6 with nothing written below .

More info in command:

```
$ ip a show wlp2s2
4: wlp2s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:9b:4a:bf:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s2
       valid_lft 857361sec preferred_lft 857361sec
    inet6 fe80::b5fa:a93c:cc6f:8f6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So, whats this IP ? What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `192.168.0.11` is an IP address from a [private IPv4 address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) that your router assigned to your computer via [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

That's a completely normal procedure. As there are not a lot of IPv4 addresses left, nearly all home routers use private addresses for the internal network, and [Network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to map the internal IPs to one external IP that's visible on the internet.

The IPv6 address is a [link local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses) that's automatically assigned. If your router would use IPv6 (though it doesn't), you'd also get an IPv6 address from your router.

Comment: Why do i have a ipv6 link local adress and not a ipv4 one ?

Comment: Because IPv6 requires a [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) address on every interface (additionally to other addresses that it may get). This address is generated from the MAC address. For IPv4, the equivalent range for local link addresses is [169.254.0.0/16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4), but these addresses are only assigned of all other mechanism to get an address fail.

Comment: Why do you mean by IPv6 requires ? Is it  some kind of a group ?

Comment: There's a sort of group that publishes standards for the internet in the form of [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)s. So the *standard* for IPv6 ("Internet Protocol Version 6") requires certain things, like that every interface gets assigned at least one address. Just like the *standards* define that IPv4 addresses consist of 4 bytes and IPv6 address of 16 bytes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything. It's an IP address.

Specifically, though, it's a *link-local* address. (See `scope link` as well as the fact that it's within the `fe80::/64` range.) In IPv6, the link-local address is generated automatically, and every interface is required to have one, even if the network doesn't advertise IPv6 connectivity.

The link-local address is *similar* to the 169.254.0.0/16 addresses sometimes seen in IPv4, and can be used for the same purpose (e.g. direct connections), but now it's also used much more widely *internally*.

For example, as the origin of broadcast ICMPv6 packets (where IPv4 would have used a blank `0.0.0.0` as the source); on networks which use Router Discovery, your default gateway will usually also be the router's link-local address.

Therefore you'll always have a link-local IPv6 address no matter how many global addresses the interface has (zero, one, multiple).

Comment: I understand the others parts but not this one : ```Therefore you'll always have a link-local IPv6 address ```why ?

Comment: Because, as stated in the 2nd paragraph, IPv6 explicitly _requires_ one to be present.